# It is possible to load a CSS class into a Javascript/Jquery variable?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

Im new in javascript/Jquery and I was wondering if is possible to load an existing css class into a variable to use it later.

Example:

```
/* CSS */
.view {
    position: absolute;
    height: 214px;
    width:1964px;
    padding:2px;
}
```

And in a javascript File load into a variable to use it like this:

```
//Javascript
var view = load(".view");

view.width // I get 1964px
view.height // I get 214px
```

Thanks.

Comment: Can you explain why you need this, as it sounds like an XY problem. What is the issue you're trying to solve?

Comment: Why this mess?? You can simply do it by $('.view').heigt(); and $('.view').width();

Comment: @AdarshMohan, not quite. The OP wants to load the class into a variable, not assign it to an element. For some reason.

Comment: ok then he can do something like this view=$('.view'); view.height(); and view.width();

Comment: Im trying to load a view dynamically in a carousel and the thing is that I do not want to hardcode the values in the carousel code.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you would do this unless you are amending HTML elements, but could you use `getComputedStyle`? Please note I am using good old JS here not jQuery...

```
/* CSS */
    .view {
        position: absolute;
        height: 214px;
        width:1964px;
        padding:2px;
    }
```

and in your JS

```
    //Javascript
    window.onload = function () { 

    var view = document.querySelector('.view'),
        styles = getComputedStyle(view);

    console.log(styles.width); 
    console.log(styles.height);
   }
```

More info [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle)

I haven't tested this but this is how I would go about it...

Comment: The same happens here. I need to have the Element loaded in the HTML before I could use its CSS class properties. There isn't other way?

Comment: Can you just wrap the code in a window.load so the HTML & CSS content is loaded before you run your code: window.onload = function () { // code } ;

Answer (score 0):

You have to use the jQuery like this:

```
var view = $('.view');
```

Then you can iterate over all elements with the class view.
Do it by:

```
$.each(view, function(){
    // then you can get all the width and height elements
    // to use them, put them in an object or in an array
})
```

Comment: For what I could see I need to have the Element loaded in the HTML before I could use its CSS class properties.